# Maintaining shape of output as of input after Boolean indexing in python

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I want help in the following problem, plz.

```
Suppose X = [1  3  0  8   
             1  4  6  0  
             2  0  7  8 ]  
mask = (X != 0)  

mask = [ T  T  F  T  
         T  T  T  F  
         T  F  T  T]  
X1 = X[(mask,np.newaxis)]
```

Its output X1 is of shape (9,1)

But i want X1 to be of (3,3), i.e., maintaining the same shape as of X except the masked entries.

```
X1 = [1  3  8   
     1  4  6   
     2  7  8 ]
```

Can someone help me plz? Thank you.

Every row of X will contain a zero and I don't want to use reshape(). Here is the working

```
X= np.array([[1,3,0,8],[1,4,6,0],[2,0,7,8]])  
mask = (X!=0)  
X1=X[(mask,np.newaxis)]
```

The  output X is of shape (9,1). Is there any way that X1 be of (3,3) as mentioned.

Comment: What if there were only 8 elements that satisfied the `X != 0` condition?

Comment: Is this related to numpy?

Comment: @mgilson, the nature of problem is that every row will contain a zero, so your mentioned issue wont be a problem.

Comment: @IronFist Yes it is related to numpy.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you might want to start on something easier in python, since your question doesn't even contain correct syntax. I'm hoping this was just a psuedocode attempt. However, here's some code to do the mask you desire.

```
import numpy as np
X = np.array([1, 3, 0, 8, 1, 4, 6, 0, 2, 0, 7, 8])
indicies_we_want = np.where(X > 0) # Results in an array containing the indicies of X we want to keep
result = np.take(X, indicies_we_want) # Filter by these indicies
result = result.reshape(3, 3) # Reshape to desired result
print result
```

This code could be condensed considerably, but I wanted to show each step as you have in your question for clarity.

As pointed out in the comments section, the reshape typically isn't a good idea unless you somehow know after filtering out 0s that you'll be left with 9 elements. In the case you described, we certainly know this, but for a given array, not so much.

Comment: Yes its a mix of code and  pseudo-code.  Every row will contain a zero so shape of array will be  fine but  I don't want to use reshape(). Here is the working code,  plz.                                                                                                                      X= np.array([[1,3,0,8],[1,4,6,0],[2,0,7,8]]).  
    mask = (X!=0).  
    X1 = X[(mask,np.newaxis)].                                                                   The  output X is of shape (9,1). Is there any way that X1 be of (3,3) as mentioned in original question, plz. Thank you for your help

Comment: My answer does exactly what you want with the call to reshape. It turns your (9,1) into (3,3). I just called the variable `result` instead of `X1`

Comment: Isn't this the same as just  doing `result = X[X != 0].reshape(3,3)`?

Comment: @PadraicCunningham Indeed :).

Answer (score 1):

```
In [173]: x=[[1,3,0,8],[1,4,6,0],[2,0,7,8]]
In [174]: xa=np.array(x)
```

solution with reshape:

```
In [175]: xa[xa!=0].reshape(3,3)
Out[175]: 
array([[1, 3, 8],
       [1, 4, 6],
       [2, 7, 8]])
```

a solution without reshape:

```
In [176]: np.array([i[i!=0] for i in xa])
Out[176]: 
array([[1, 3, 8],
       [1, 4, 6],
       [2, 7, 8]])
```

Obviously both depend on there being only one deletion per row.

You aren't deleting a common column; nothing in your code tells the underlying numpy that the result will be reshapeable.  So boolean indexing operates on the flattened array.

```
In [177]: xa[xa!=0]
Out[177]: array([1, 3, 8, 1, 4, 6, 2, 7, 8])
In [178]: xa.flat[xa.flat!=0]
Out[178]: array([1, 3, 8, 1, 4, 6, 2, 7, 8])
```

I could throw in an extra 0, and this indexing would still work the same; but the efforts to reshape it to 3x3 will fail.

---

Keep in mind that the underlying data buffer is flat, 1d, and that it only displays as 2d because of the `shape` and `striding` attributes.  Selecting elements (or skipping some) will produce a copy, and a 1d copy is just as easy, even faster, than a 2d one.  `reshape` doesn't change the data buffer, just the `shape` attribute.